# How does correcting grammar and removing conversational language "deviate from original intent"?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

I recently suggested an edit for [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44205567/hi-i-was-just-wondering-how-to-switch-my-default-python-3-6-idle-from-64-bit-to). The reason I edited it was to get rid of the (for lack of a better word) "child-like" language used (for example, "Hi, I was just wondering"...in the title, etc.) and also to change some of the grammar around to make it more readable.

The edit was rejected, as [you can see in the review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16243400). I don't necessarily have a problem with that, to each their own, and if people don't think it needs to be changed, fine; I've done my part. What I don't understand is the reasoning behind it. Two of the reviewers gave the reason of "deviating from original intent". This makes no sense to me, because I don't see how my edits changed the intent. The same question was still asked. I would just like to know the reasoning behind this.

I have looked at other questions about "deviating from original intent", but most of those are about changing code, or other things which I did not do.

Comment: I would have approved it.  Interestingly, one of the people who rejected your edit has *approved 579 edit suggestions and rejected 1836 edit suggestions*.  Makes me think they might be too picky or they just skip the easy approves and look for suggestion to reject.

Comment: The review looks like an audit at first sight.

Comment: The third edit to that question should have been rejected (if that was possible).

Comment: @JoshCaswell Second as well, or at least severely improved upon.

Comment: I disagree, @krillgar; the second edit is already a substantial improvement. If it was a suggested edit, I would have accepted it but added to it.

Comment: @JoshCaswell That's why I said "severely improved upon". There was a LOT in there that needed fixed originally, but the change to "how di I make it open at 32 bit by default?" needs to be rewritten enough as well.

Comment: "The reason I edited it was to get rid of the **(for lack of a better word)**  "child-like" language used" Lack of words? What about Colloquial? Informal? Vernacular? Conversational? Natural? Plain? Demotic? Chatty? Dialectal?.... Words, there are plenty, and I'm sure native speakers can think of even more! :)

Comment: @xDaizu I said "for lack of a better word", because I liked that word the best, but it didn't sound the most professional. Should have said, "for lack of a word I like better" I guess.

Comment: Is it wrong that I knew who one of the reviewers was going to be before I opened it? I already flagged them months ago about their terrible rejections, but nothing was done.

Comment: @xDaizu And yet, none of those words are *better* for what the OP means. "Fixed grammar and awkward phrasing" would have sufficed as the edit description.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Not wrong, but disheartening. If flagging doesn't work, you may want to consider bypassing the flags and send an e-mail to staff if you can build a strong case for it.

Comment: Editing a question to "improve" the use of language should only be done if the question is otherwise unclear to the reader, not because you prefer a different style of writing. I *hate* having my own posts edited to use words or phrases that I would never use in my own writing.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Thanks for your edit, and try to not be discouraged.

To answer your question: it **does not** deviate from the author's intent, and likely people just declined it because of the large-ish change from

> I have just made a game and I would like to open by double clicking on its file but it doesn't work because my IDLE is set to open 64 bit by default but all my 'plugins' like pygame are in my 32 bit IDLE.

to

> I have just made a game, and would like to open by double clicking on its file, but I need to open it in 32 bit IDLE, because all my 'plugins' like pygame are 32 bit. By default, IDLE opens in 64 bit.

At a *glance* it could certainly seem like you changed what the author was saying, but actually reading over it it's clear you've just improved what it said because the first instance is a bit of a mouthful. Your wording improved it without changing intent.

Perhaps your edit note could've been something like

> Removed fluff from title and changed long run-on sentence into a more readable sentence

But I doubt it would've helped. Likely the reviewers weren't paying that much attention. That said, always do your best to ensure your edit note accurately reflects your changes.

Comment: AKA: lots of red and green! Must reject!

Comment: things like this happening over and over made me just stop reviewing and editing things.

Comment: @Tas Thanks for the advice. I couldn't come up with a better "changes made" sentence, but will strive to not make it so ambiguous.

Comment: @Zimano no, don't stop reviewing. If you do then you are being part of the problem. Try to skip drivel reviews and reject and edit, or improve those that you know would be conclude in not improving the quality of the post.

Comment: Lots of red & green for me, most often means 'Skip', as I can't always be bothered to go through it all. I think I would have approved this one though.

Comment: @Zimano - you and hundreds of others, myself included

Comment: "Likely the reviewers weren't paying that much attention". ===> "Stop and listen. That was an audit to make sure you were paying attention. You **FAILED**". hahahahahha

Comment: Yeah, the given edit reason is lacking. `Edited to conform to Stack Overflow norms` seems like a wordier `Improved formatting`

Comment: @Machavity: Not at all. One is a conscious attempt at summarizing a mundane copy edit without being verbose, the other is *placeholder text*, or at least filler text that editors use when *they can't even be bothered to think of anything meaningful to say*. Case in point: 90% of edits that read "Improved formatting" weren't made to improve formatting at all.

Comment: @BoltClock: Yeah, the only time I would say "Improved formatting" is if the original *had* lots **of** random *words* set in *bold* or **italics** and I had just changed everything to roman.

Comment: Editors suck, almost always. Who raised these people?!

Comment: I stopped editing after I had an edit rejected for being too big a change, and another one for being too small a change.

Answer (score 2):

Since you had trouble coming up with an edit description, here are some key words and phrases I use when editing. Some I picked up in my English/writing classes during my school days. Others are just obvious or something I can up with.

- grammar: This covers things like word order, verb tenses, prepositions ("of", "to", "on"), articles ("a", "the", "some"), pronouns, run on and incomplete sentences, plural vs. singular, etc.
- mechanics: This covers spelling, punctuation, capitalization, etc.
- word choice: This is when the word chosen doesn't *quite* mean exactly what they intended to communicate.
- awkward phrasing: This is for when I can't really pin down a technical reason it's wrong, but I know that it definitely doesn't read very smoothly. (This sometimes corresponds to when it doesn't read like native speech.)
- formatting: I only use this when I'm doing Markdown. Turning something into a code block or a block quote, fixing some list indentation, bold, italics, turning lines into headers, etc.

If you can, always be **more specific**. But if the changes you made are too wide ranging to stuff all the details into that description, sticking "fixed" in front of the above phrases can help summarize in a lot of cases. Try not to let these summaries stand completely alone whenever possible.