# Am I being too harsh with edit suggestions reviews?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I have done an acceptable number of edit suggestions review, and I think I'm somewhat trying to stay up to date with meta on what we should be accepting or rejecting. For instance, I have been starting to [approve minor improvements](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252249/576767), as long as they fix everything in the post, whereas before I would have rejected as too minor.

However, I still reject *way* more than I approve, like three times more. I try to be fair, but will reject and edit instead of approve and edit when I feel something is lacking from the suggestion.

This [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349950/how-does-correcting-grammar-and-removing-conversational-language-deviate-from-o?cb=1#comment477523_349950) by NathanOlivier (especially the upvotes) makes me pause however. It seems that lots of rejections is a signal for some people that something is amiss. (FTR, I think I would have approved that specific suggestion, but who knows).

Hence, I would like to know what we think about that. I actually think the contrary, and when I see reviewers with more approvals than rejections, they also tend to approve anything, edits that are wrong, useless or leave plenty of stuff to be improved.

I don't expect the reader to actually roam through my edits, but as of now the stats are

> Félix Gagnon-Grenier has approved 374 edit suggestions and rejected 1161 edit suggestions and improved 221 edit suggestions

Is that a signal that I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: It's difficult to tell if you're doing right or wrong but believe me I see a lot of edits being made that are utter crap and _should_ be rejected. I see more bad than good and so them stats kind of do add up to what I would expect to see from someone who is taking the time to review.

Comment: When I see high numbers like that it just gives me pause.  Normally a high reject rate is not a concern(normally it is a high approve rate that signals a robo reviewer).  There are very legitimate reasons to reject more then you approve.  One of them is my scenario where I skip a lot of easy approves and look for edits that should be rejected or should be approved but might be rejected.

Comment: The reject number includes the "Reject & Edit" option, right? I Reject & Edit *a lot*. I'm currently at 84 approved, 429 rejected, and 124 improved. I will Improve & Edit where someone clearly just missed a capitalization or a period but a lot of edits leave or even add major issues. I've also been worried I reject too much and will find myself skipping things I want to reject.

Comment: _".., as long as they fix everything in the post, .."_ there is no such requirement. You need to accept those (assuming they are actually improvements), or accept and edit to add further improvements.

Comment: Just commenting to say that I think my edit reviews (few of them that I have) tend to go the other way: I probably approve more than I reject because sometimes I can't tell and would prefer to skip an edit that's bad, but where I can't tell it was bad because I don't understand the subject material (I've been occasionally hit by an audit because the original and the edit were equally not-understandable due to the subject nature).

Comment: [Am I being too harsh...?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betteridge%27s_law_of_headlines)

Comment: @AndrasDeak hah! ta ;)

Comment: I feel tempted to close-vote as "primarily opinion based" or "too broad". It all depends on which edits you actually get. Statistics don't tell anything for a particular instance. So if you get a lot of bad edits and take this task seriously (which this meta shows), you naturally have a lot of rejects. I'd start worriyng if most of your rejets get accepted eventually. Wrt the reject mentioned: I did not check it, but every human errs from time to time.

Comment: What is worrying is the [2nd edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44205567/2) made on that post. One step forward (out of three needed) and two steps back. And that by a 33K rep user.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Having high reject:approval ratio is just unusual on its own, not bad. There are several possible reasons for this, and some are better than others.

1. You are extremely selective about which reviews you handle, and <kbd>Skip</kbd> many of them, especially the simple approvals that anyone can and will handle.

   [This is great, and more reviewers should do this!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292007/encouraging-attentive-suggested-edit-reviewers-to-skip-every-uncontroversial-rev)
2. You have very high standards for edits.

   This is less great, since suggestions are supposed to be fairly free-flowing in general, even if they aren't terribly impressive, but at least it's commendably motivated by a desire for quality.
3. You're pretty sure a lot of edits are bad but aren't really sure what makes them bad, so you just look for edits with existing reject votes and follow along.
   ***or***
   You want to avoid audits, know that all audits in Suggested Edits are known-bad, and therefore just reject everything that is at all confusing.

   No… just no. Stop reviewing, please, if you can't take the time to do things right.

In your case, you appear to be deliberately moving from 2 to 1, which is a good position to be in. (For example, [this R&E from a month ago would probably deserve Improving instead in future](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15967225).) Keep up the good work of balancing a smooth flow of editing to improve posts with reasonable standards for those improvements, and you'll be fine.

NathanOliver's comment, which I upvoted, was referring to a reviewer who appears (from my own earlier checking of over a hundred of their reviews) to fall largely in the third category. An awful lot of their rejections (especially the ludicrously wrong ones) tend to play follow the leader, coming in as the second (or occasionally third, in times past) rejection and mimicking the previous reason no matter how ill-fitting.

Comment: Re: your point number 3, I did see your comment about the flag on that last post. A moderator looked over their review activity last time and, while we suspect what you do, it was hard for us to find specific cases of them doing damage with these reviews. It's one thing to approve bad edits, that's easy to identify and the damage is clear, but it's much harder to find good edits being rejected. If you have a few good recent examples of this, flag us with them and that might be enough to act on. I'll say that they're maybe the first person I've ever seen doing this, if true.

Comment: @BradLarson: Thanks. I had a fair few URLs to their reviews last time that didn't all fit in a flag (1200 characters go!); maybe a private chat room would work well to pass those along?

Comment: If you could find recent ones, that'd be preferred. People get pretty angry when we ban them from review, so we want to be able to point to them doing current and ongoing damage with their reviews. We typically don't ban for review actions taken months ago, even if they were awful at the time. Many times, the system will have caught them in the interim and they'll have had a chance to reform.

Comment: @BradLarson: OK, I'll see what I can do.